# fancyhdr equivalent in ConTeXt

Tags: header-footer, context, fancyhdr

In LaTeX the `fancyhdr` package provides the `lhead`, `chead` and `rhead` macros that allow me to create the left, center and right parts of the header. These macros also enable me to treat each part of the header as a column. For example the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{\textbf{A\\ B}}
\chead{\textbf{C\\ D}}
\rhead{\textbf{E}}

\begin{document}

Some Text

\end{document}
```

Produces the following document:
[image: MWE]

Notice how A and B are stacked on top of each other.

How can I achieve this in ConTeXt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See `\setupheadertexts` on the [ConTeXt wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupheadertexts)  and the [ConTeXt user manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/cont-eni.pdf).

Also see the [header and footer](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Headers_and_Footers) section on the ConTeXt wiki.

```
% The default header is bigger, and by default, the header is top aligned.
% So change the header size
\setuplayout
  [header=2\lineheight,
   headerdistance=\lineheight]

% By default, no frames are drawn around the header.
% Change that to draw a rule at the bottom of the header.
\setupbackgrounds[header][text][frame=off, bottomframe=on]

% Set the headers in bold.
\setupheader[style=bold]

% By default, the header is a \hbox. We define a dedicated \vbox to 
% place multiple lines in the header.
\defineframed[headerframed]
             [frame=off,
              align=middle,
              width=fit]

\setupheadertexts[\headerframed{C \\ D}]
\setupheadertexts[\headerframed{A \\ B}][\headerframed{E \\ F}]

\starttext
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]